# How to use GROUP BY after multiple UNION SELECT without receiving NONAGGREGATED COLUMN error?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, union, incompatibility

Let me explain to you my problem with an example:

Given a couple of member_id's, I need to find on which team they belong to:

```
SELECT 
team_name, member_id, last_updated
    FROM
        (SELECT 'red team' AS team_name, su.* 
    FROM 
        'red_table' su
        UNION SELECT 
        'blue team' AS team_name, mu.*
    FROM 
        'blue_table' mu 
        UNION SELECT 
        'green team' AS team_name, mh.*
    FROM 
        'green_table' mh 
        UNION SELECT 
        'black team' AS team_name cm.*
    FROM 'black_table' cm) a
WHERE
    member_id IN ('123456','987654', '666666')
```

Works perfectly fine:

```
team_name | member_id | last_updated
blue_team | 987654 | 2020-03-11
green_team | 123456 | 2020-04-08
black_team | 123456 | 2018-08-05
```

However, my problems started when I needed to discard older information, leaving only the most recent, as shown:

```
team_name | member_id | last_updated
blue_team | 987654 | 2020-03-11
green_team | 123456 | 2020-04-08
```

To do that, I added the following lines:

```
SELECT 
 team_name, member_id, 
 MAX(last_updated) AS most_recent
FROM (

SELECT 
team_name, member_id, last_updated
    FROM
        (SELECT 'red team' AS team_name, su.* 
    FROM 
        'red_table' su
        UNION SELECT 
        'blue team' AS team_name, mu.*
    FROM 
        'blue_table' mu 
        UNION SELECT 
        'green team' AS team_name, mh.*
    FROM 
        'green_table' mh 
        UNION SELECT 
        'black team' AS team_name cm.*
    FROM 'black_table' cm) a
WHERE
    member_id IN ('123456','987654', '666666')

) as test

GROUP BY team_name
```

Whenever I try to use the code, I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [1055] [42000]: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.member_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

After searching here on S.O. I found the following solution

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

but is not applicable to my case because I have no admin control of the database(s).

Please, could you show me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please include the actual query which is generating this error.

Comment: Sure Tim, included as requested

Comment: Adding GROUP BY team_name, member_id solved my problem, thank you very much! How can I  mark your answer as the solution @forpas?